# Switch user with "sudo su - username" using SSH keys

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I've been trying to use ssh keys in order to be able to switch from one user to another user on the same Linux machine/server by using `sudo su - username`.

What i want to do is: I have several accounts on one server. 
I want to lock those account with `passwd -l username`, 
and allow access only with SSH keys, by ssh-ing from one user to the other on the same machine, e.g., :  `[user1@server]$  ssh user2@server`

I did this by copying the public key of `user1` to the `authorized_keys` file of `user2` and it works fine.

But the other thing that i would like also to do, is to be able to `sudo su - user2` from `user1`, by using the ssh keys, so i can avoid the password prompting.

e.g., `[user1@server]$ sudo su - user2`

I have modified the sshd_config file, and uncomment the fields:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
```

but still i am not able to do it.

I also tried what i found on the internet regarding agent forwarding, but nothing.

Can anyone help me on how to do this or point me to the right direction?

Comment: `sudo` does not know anything about, nor does it care about, `ssh` keys. They are entirely different things. In order to get passwordless `sudo` working, you need to configure `sudo` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

To get sudo to work passwordless to another user these are the changes required (perform them with super user access):

edit /etc/sudoers

```
visudo
```

Config changes

```
# Allow user to sudo su as anyone without password
user    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
%group  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

# Allow user to become another user
user    ALL=(user2)    NOPASSWD: ALL
%group  ALL=(user2)    NOPASSWD: ALL
```

now with the latter sudo su - user2 should work

The only stumbling block was the user to be added to sudo group

```
usermod -a -G sudo user
```

The examples above in the config shows the user first then by group - you only need 1 of the two -

Edited:

```
visudo

%group2    ALL=(ALL:ALL)    PASSWD: ALL
%group1    ALL=(ALL:ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
```

add run group

```
groupadd group1
groupadd group2
```

so for users that require a password

```
usermod -a -G group2 user1
usermod -a -G group2 user2
etc..
```

for users that require no password:

```
usermod -a -G group nuser1
usermod -a -G group nuser2
etc
```

Comment: Hi vahid, thank you for you response.
This way i don't make any use of the ssh keys. Let me clarify what i am trying to do. 
Let's say i have user1, user2, and user3.
I want user1 to be able to switch to user2 using ssh keys and without being prompted for password. The same goes for user2 to user1. But i don't want user3 to be able to switch to any o the other users without password.

Here in this example i am considering only 3 user, but in real i have about 50 users in once machine. So, going to the sudoers file and adding for each user of those 50 is not that efficient, unless i am wrong.

Comment: do it via groups then - create groups that include the variants and then include the users as part of the variations so group1 {allowed users } group2 {different rule } then using the sudo config you would then need two lines %group and %group2   -- There is no relation between sudo and ssh config..

Comment: http://www.evans.io/posts/ssh-agent-for-sudo-authentication/  take a look here to try and combine the two - there is on a typical set up no relations..

Comment: Setting the editor isn't "required". It should be avoided. Even if it's only for the current session it has a potential to confuse inexperienced users. Also you forgot to add "sudo".

Comment: Albin removed it, unsure what you mean by forgot to add sudo ? can u edit update it ?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` has nothing to do with SSH and `sshd` config.

What you really want is a PAM module that will use SSH public keys. I'm not sure what are your reasons as the whole idea seems a bit strange, but, well. [`pam_ssh`](http://pam-ssh.sourceforge.net/) is the module that does this.

Comment: Hi kirelagin,
The reason why i want to do this, is because i want to switch to another users on the same machine without having to become first root and then switch to the other user.
So, i thought the SSH keys would be a solution to this. But i guess i was wrong.
Instead, i want to switch from one user to another (without becoming root) with sudo su - user2, and avoid the password prompting. So i thought that ssh keys would help here.

Comment: Sure, ssh keys can help you, but you don't need `sudo` then, `su` is enough. As I mentioned, you can use `pam_ssh` module and configure your PAM to use it for `su` authentication. Note, that you will anyway have to enter the password to decrypt your SSH key, becuase if your key is not encrypted with a password it's kinda useless.

Comment: @kirelagin - ssh-agents do the job for not typing passwords

Answer (score 2):

in some cases (eg you haven't root permissions) you can use something like

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user2@localhost
```

And then log in with

```
ssh user2@localhost
```

Comment: In short, you can login to other user on the same server/pc by first enabling passwordless access to the other user and then login using `ssh <otheruser>@0`.

Answer (score -1):

This actually can be simplified down to logging into one user with sudo via a single ssh connection.

> user@host:~$ ssh user0@remote.tld
> ...
> user0@remote.tld:~$ sudo -iu user1

Where user is your local user, user0 is your sudo administrator on your remote host, and user1 is the user required.

To disable the password on user1:

> user0@remote.tld:~$ sudo passwd -l user1

I don't really suggest disabling passwords entirely for using sudo issued commands. Though, should one feel the need to disable passwords on a sudo user:

> user@host:~$ visudo

```
%sudoers ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

That should take care of things in a more "simplified" way. Though, have a look around for commands like:

> user@host:~$ ssh -L 127.0.0.1:2222:127.0.0.1:22 user0@remote.tld

another terminal:

> user@host:~$ ssh -p user1@127.0.0.1

which might be something to look at.